# Clear child component state from parent

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a parent component form that holds multiple child components that make up the form such as checkboxes etc.

My child component looks like the following:

```
export default class Exhibitors extends Component {
    state = {
        exhibitors: [
            {id: 1, value: "true", label: "YES", checked: false},
            {id: 2, value: "false", label: "NO", checked: false},
        ]
    }

    handleChange = value => {
        this.props.onChange("exhibitors", (value.target.value === 'true'));
        this.setState(prevState => ({
            exhibitors: prevState.exhibitors.map(
                el => el.value === value.target.value ? {...el, checked: true} : el
            )
        }))
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Row>
                    <Col>
                        <h4 className="ui centered question-header text-center">DO YOU HAVE EXHIBITORS?</h4>
                    </Col>
                </Row>
                <Row>
                    {
                        this.state.exhibitors.map((type) => {
                            return (<Radio name="exhibitors" key={type.value}
                                           onChange={this.handleChange} {...type} />)
                        })
                    }
                </Row>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

And then my parent form looks like

```
export default class MainForm extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }
    

    render() {
        
        return (
            <Container>
                <Formik
                    initialValues={{
                        exhibitors: 0,
                    }}
                    onSubmit={async (values, {setFieldValue}) => {
                        
                        this.setState({loading: true})
                        const api = process.env.REACT_APP_API_ENDPOINT;
                        const data = JSON.stringify(this.state)
                        const headers = {
                            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                        }

                        axios
                            .post(api, data, {
                                headers: headers,
                                timeout: 10000
                            })
                            .then((response) => {
                                document.getElementById("platform-match").reset();
                                window.scrollTo(0, 0)
                                console.log(response)
                            })
                            .catch((error) => {
                                console.log(error)
                            })
                    }}
                >
                    {({values, setFieldValue, setFieldTouched}) => (
                        <Form id="platform-match">

                            <Exhibitors
                                onChange={setFieldValue}
                            />
                        
                            <Row>
                                <Col>
                                    <button type="submit" className="checkbox-label submit">
                                        Submit
                                    </button>
                                </Col>
                            </Row>
                        </Form>
                    )}
                </Formik>
            </Container>
        )
    }
}
```

When I submit my form I need to change the exhibitors checked values to false from my parent component, I can't see how this is possible at the moment, unless I refresh the page entirely which seems like a bad way of doing things.

Is there a way I can set the checked values to false from my parent component?

Comment: If you are trying to change children's states from a parent, one approach is that you can store the children's states in parent instead, and pass it down as props. This way, both your parent and children component can edit the state.